# How to combine two independent android styles to create a new one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

This question has been asked many times, but the asking has not been precise enough or maybe the answers are not answering the question I have in mind. Here is my problem. I have two styles

- HorseAppearance
- DonkeyAppearance

They are established and independent styles. Now I want to combine them into another style called MuleAppearance, which in turn may have its own attributes. How might I do *that*?

For example (please don't get distracted) the following does not work

```
<style name="HorseAppearance.MuleAppearance" parent="DonkeyAppearance">
....
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of answers or documentation, I guess you would do something like:

```
<style name="IndependentOne">
  //items
</style>
<style name="IndependentTwo">
  //items
</style>
 <style name="IndependentOne.IndependentTwo">
  //items from IndepedentTwo
</style>
```

That way you have two independent styles to use then anywhere and a combination of both to use where applicable

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure you want combine finally 3 (HorseAppearance + DonkeyAppearance + MuleAppearance) or just 2 styles (some time HorseAppearance + MuleAppearance and another time DonkeyAppearance + MuleAppearance.

### To merge e.g. HorseAppearance + MuleAppearance...

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
<application ... android:theme="@style/HorseAppearance" ...>
```

```
// src/mule/res/values/styles.xml
<style name="MuleAppearance">
    ...
</style>
```

```
// src/horse/res/values/styles.xml
<style name="HorseAppearance" parent="MuleAppearance">
    ...
</style>
```

### To merge DonkeyAppearance + HorseAppearance + MuleAppearance...

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
<application ... android:theme="@style/DonkeyAppearance" ...>
```

```
// src/mule/res/values/styles.xml
<style name="MuleAppearance">
    ...
</style>
```

```
// src/horse/res/values/styles.xml
<style name="HorseAppearance" parent="MuleAppearance">
    ...
</style>
```

```
// src/donkey/res/values/styles.xml
<style name="DonkeyAppearance" parent="HorseAppearance">
    ...
</style>
```